# Springboot upgrade from 1.x to 2.3.x MySQL performance issue

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, tomcat, persistence, connection-pooling

Trying to upgrade Springboot

```
from 1.x/java8  to 2.3.x/java 11(AWS Corretto 11)

MySQL: Aurora
Connectionpool: tomcat datasource

Issue: with the upgraded version DB CPU go very high and DB connections in 800-1000 where as 1.x with same connection pool was 200-300 connections and CPU in 40s
This is detected in performance test.
```

This line is added for the upgraded 2.3.x

```
 "spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"


## DB connection pool
    spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
    spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=30000
    spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=150
    spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
    spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=150
    spring.datasource.tomcat.initialize-size=10
    spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=10
    spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1
    spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query-timeout=5
    spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=5000
    spring.datasource.tomcat.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=30000
    spring.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned=true
    spring.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned-timeout=60
    spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true
```

Any suggestions from experts to match DB CPU and connections with previous version?

```
springboot 1.x:
CPU:40-50%
Connections : 200-300


springboot 2.3.x:
CPU:100%
Connections : 800-1000
```

DB process list have several "cleaned up" state too.

gradle dependencies

```
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"){
    exclude group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', module: 'elasticsearch-rest-client'
    exclude group: 'com.zaxxer', module: 'HikariCP'
}
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc') {
    exclude group: 'com.zaxxer', module: 'HikariCP'
}
implementation('org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc')
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
```

Logs says its picking right tomcat.datasource as

org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@35ee466f
{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=true; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver;
maxActive=150; maxIdle=150; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=30000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:mysql:aurora://DB/schema?connectTimeout=2000;
username=root; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=5; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=true; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; useStatementFacade=true; }

slow query log - after removing server/sensitive details
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5jbh.jpg

From comment:

```
CREATE TABLE history (
    capi_id varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    major_revision bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
    minor_revision bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
    version varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    document_id varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL, 
    operation varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
    status varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
    transaction_id varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (capi_id,major_revision,minor_revision,version)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Use the [_slowlog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) to find which queries are having the most impact; then let's discuss them.

Comment: Thanks Rick.
Managed to get slow queries in to the table of aurora-db.

     Select * from mysql.slow_log
shown 41 entries but coonection were close to 1000.

Comment: What was the value of `long_query_time`?  If it was the default of 10 (seconds), then you have some really slow queries.  Please show us the contents of the log (truncate it if it is too big).

Comment: long_query_time=2 and from the log, there is just 1 query took >10 which is 13 sec.

Comment: Let's see some of them.  (In my book, even 2 seconds is too long, and can probably be sped up.)

Comment: partial screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5jbh.jpg

Comment: Query format(id as text edited )

select history0_.capi_id as capi_id1_9_0_, history0_.major_revision as major_re2_9_0_, history0_.minor_revision as minor_re3_9_0_, history0_.version as version4_9_0_, history0_.document_id as document5_9_0_, history0_.operation as operatio6_9_0_, history0_.status as status7_9_0_, history0_.transaction_id as transact8_9_0_ from history history0_ where history0_.capi_id='ID' and history0_.major_revision=1485757299000 and history0_.minor_revision=0 and history0_.version='publish'

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM is there?

Answer (score 0):

For this query (from Comment):

```
select  history0_.capi_id as capi_id1_9_0_,
        history0_.major_revision as major_re2_9_0_,
        history0_.minor_revision as minor_re3_9_0_,
        history0_.version as version4_9_0_,
        history0_.document_id as document5_9_0_,
        history0_.operation as operatio6_9_0_,
        history0_.status as status7_9_0_,
        history0_.transaction_id as transact8_9_0_
    from  history history0_
    where  history0_.capi_id='ID'
      and  history0_.major_revision=1485757299000
      and  history0_.minor_revision=0
      and  history0_.version='publish'
```

`history` may benefit from

```
INDEX(capi_id, major_revision, minor_revision, version)
```

(The order of the index's columns does not matter *for this query*.)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE history`.

It seems quite unusual for those `INSERTs` to be taking 2-4 seconds.  Perhaps some of them are `INSERT ... SELECT ...` and I can't see the full query?

Comment: Create table:

CREATE TABLE `history` (
  `capi_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `major_revision` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `minor_revision` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `version` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `document_id` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operation` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_id` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`capi_id`,`major_revision`,`minor_revision`,`version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: insert queries: 
insert into history (document_id, operation, status, transaction_id, capi_id, major_revision, minor_revision, version) values ('a10f288b-c93e-492c-bbac-7c47b78e4777', 'CREATE', NULL, '24ffd6ae-501d-4c2f-aaf3-122749pt1234', '75adc213a4d9324d8a91bbecd16f2e10', 1641864469267, 0, 'draft')

Comment: insert Query type #2:  
insert into document (capi_id, date_created, document_path, domain, headers, http_verb, notification_status, operation, origin, origin_id, query_string, status, subtype, system_updated, transaction_id, type, date_updated, user, validation_msg, id) values ('79a1311744550c562dd238f37741bb2a', '2022-01-11 01:26:43.901', 'document/41bb2a/79a1/79a1311744550c562dd238f37741bb2a/b880c45a-e72c-492c-a358-0ae1996a53ed', NULL, '{\content-length\":\"15468\"

Comment: insert query #3 reference to table-document  :                                                                     insert into related_asset (capi_id, enterprise_id, origin, origin_id, document_id, parent_id, related_parent_id, status, status_message, type, id) values ('c884381a3e2dbf78ba58cb1d140028c4', NULL, 'system2', 'crop-986ecf6f1998dbe20d344773e94b6920', 'c5a047db-8023-4d77-a2d4-dfeb25a8d9c9', '47ed474a-d543-11e7-b11a-d81dcd126735', NULL, 'OK', '', 'image', 'c7bf0047-4382-42f9-bc88-67adb046f37c')

Comment: @Indu - What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`? How much RAM is there?

Comment: 'innodb_buffer_pool_size', '1610612736'
and RAM is 4GB(db.t2.medium)

Comment: @Indu - That seems OK.  I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks RIck for the analysis and inputs. We now trying tuning of connection pooling. If all fixed will update here, will be helpful for similar tech-teams

Answer (score 0):

Solution:DB connection pool issue resolved by switching to hikari connection pool which is default for springboot 2.x.
There were high latency and 504 gatewaytimeout(or nginx 499)in application load test which is resolved by reducing db & property reloads(PeriodicReloadingTrigger)
VisualVM helped to connect to remote ec2 on load test to see waiting threads,which were hikari hits.